# How to add class on hover of multiple list in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here I have some static list. I need to change the class on hover and mouseout of the list individually.But here class is getting changed for all list at a time. Here is code below

### home.component.html

```
<div>
<ul>
<li [ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">test1</li>
<li [ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">test2</li>
<li [ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">test3</li>
<li [ngClass]="color" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">test4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

    /* First data */
    console.log('hello');
  }
  color:string = 'red';

changeStyle($event){
  this.color = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'yellow' : 'red';
}
}
```

### css

```
.yellow{
border-bottom:1px solid;    
}
.red{
background:red;
color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  $event.target.className. It work for current event class. Try the below solution It will work.

```
changeStyle($event){
    $event.target.className= $event.target.className == 'red' ? 'yellow' : 'red';
  }
```

or

```
changeStyle($event){
 $event.target.className = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'yellow' : 'red';
}
```